# wait for a time

Tags: c++, linux, datetime, sleep

I have a requirement to start my application at certain time. I don’t want to be put in the corn job.  My executable is an application and like to start on 2011-Jan-20
So I have to run it as
./app –date 2011-Jan-20

Here problem is, how I will calculates the time difference from current and date supplied in command line option.

I don’t want to write won function. Is there any in build function are available  for  such type of time difference. ( c and Linux)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do?  Are you trying to write code in your app that will let you run the command now but have it use a timer to know when to start?  And what's wrong with the Cron system?  It's a tried and tested system that works really well.

Comment: If you could explain *why* you don't want to use `cron` people might be better able to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe `man at`  could be useful for you.

Comment: Jmort253: You are right. this requirement is one option of application. In other case it will run normal way.

Comment: In other way, user working in night and want to run this on next day at 8 AM. So, corn is not a better option. Here time is not fixed .

Comment: @Saurabh01: `echo "./app" | at 20.01.2011 08:00` is by far the most simple and reliable way to achieve your goal. Why can't you use it ?

Comment: Not being a unix user, I thought you really did mean 'corn job', so I looked it up in the Urban Dictionary. Not for the faint-hearted! Perhaps you should fix this before others get caught :-)

Comment: @TonyK - Lol, if I had $1 for every piece of code I've seen that had Cornjob in it instead of Cron, I'd be a wealthy guy.  It's a very common misspelling.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for there solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the difference between the start time and now in milliseconds and then wait for that many milliseconds by passing that number as a timeout argument to `select()` or `epoll()`.

To calculate the difference, one way is to first convert your date string to `struct tm` using `strptime()` and then pass it to `mktime()` which is going to give you a number of seconds since unix epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Then get the current time by using `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()`, they also report time passed since unix epoch. Convert the start time and the current time to seconds and subtract the values.

Comment: In newer kernels you should use a [timerfd](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) with this approach.

Comment: @Sam: `timerfd()` is a nice feature but not essential. Event demultiplexing libraries like http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/ usually use timeout argument to `select()` to wait till the earliest timer expiry or file descriptor readiness or a signal. In other words, at the implementation level you don't need to schedule waiting for all timers at the same time, only till the earliest one.

Answer (score 4):

I know you're expecting a `C` answer but this might interest you:

Since you're on linux, the system provides already an efficient way to schedule ponctual tasks: `at`

In your case, an user that would like to run his task on the 20.01.2011 at 8AM, would just type:

```
echo "./app" | at 08:00 20.01.2011
```

The task will be run using the credentials of the user. Note that `at` also accept relative time directives such as `at now +1 day`. It is a powerful tool which ships with most Linux distributions by default.

The list of scheduled jobs can be get using:

```
atq
```

And you can even remove scheduled jobs using:

```
atrm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel or lose sleep over a problem  that doesn't really exist.  I think the guy should accept your answer.  This is good to know!